# lte and gte in mongodb with java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am working with Mongodb and I need to retrieve set of records with range of specified dates,like from date to to date.

I am using criteria object from java to form a query

But it not considering the equals date

ex:

fromDate:15-09-2017
tdate:23-09-2017
in to date it is not considering 23-09-2017 since it is lte(less than equals) it should take it and fetch the records.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("b").elemMatch(Criteria.where("startDate").lte(date).and("endDate").gte(date) )
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete, viable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example - can you post more of your code, and add a tag for the Java library you're using? The query you've given is incomplete, so it does not make sense.

Comment: Use dates instead of string or atleast use iso format date string like `yyyy-mm-dd` for comparison to work.

Comment: Yes, I am using ISO date format only.

Comment: `dd-mm-yyyy` is not an iso format. Can you add a sample document to the collection ?

Comment: Yes, I am using ISO date format only, I am taking input from user as yyyy-mm-dd and parsing it to UTC format and then querying with that date since in mongo date is stored as <YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>" and then prepared query with criteria.It is not fecthing the records with current date as  example:fromDate:2017-09-15,toDate:2017-09-23 then it should also fetch the records on 2017-09-23  since i am using lte(less than equals).but this date records are not fetched from Mongo.I have checked in mongo there are records.

Comment: Can you add a sample document that your expecting to return to the post ? Why do you use `elemMatch` ? Is `b` an array ?